# Are these conditions sufficient for the process to be continuous?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

The text book I’m working on considers the following SDE:
$dX(t) = \mu(t)dt + \sigma(t)dW(t)$, where $\mu$ is defined to be a càdlàg predictable and finite variation process, while $\sigma$ is a square integrable, predictable, non-decreasing process. Then it rules out the possibility of any jump in the process $X$. Is it correct to conclude that the process $\mu$ is continuous and hence has finite quadratic variation?